# ArrayList vs Generic collections

Tags: c#-2.0

what are pros and cons to use ArrayList instead generic collection in NET 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic collections are type-safe - you cannot put a `string` into a `List<int>` - and don't require constant boxing/unboxing from `object`.

`ArrayList` on the other hand can handle a mix of different elements - this can be a plus in certain cases.

My take: typically I always use `List<T>` - unless I really need something that can handle `int, string, DateTime` etc. at the same time (very rare occasions).

Comment: I use `List<object>` when I need to handle any object. IMHO it's ok to consider `ArrayList` deprecated.

Comment: To add: the generic List<T> and ArrayList are in algorithmic complexity the same, so I would advise to always use the generic collection for type safety. Mixing different elements in a single list is not a good practice.

Comment: "Mixing different elements in a single list is not a good practice"
yes. I think you're right Marc.